# junit test cases for SpringBoot application which uses non JPA Repository object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I am writing an springboot component which is simply responsible for auditing login operation.
Since component is only responsible to write into database and there will be no retrieve(select) operation on table. I am simply using `@Repository`(org.springframework.data.repository.Repository) package and implemented method with insert into statement to write in database.

```
@Repository
public interface AuditRepository extends Repository<UserAudit,String> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "insert into user_audit(user_id,datetime,function_code,ip_address) values (:user_id,:datetime,:function_code,:ip_address)",nativeQuery = true)
    @Transactional
    public void recordUserAudit(@Param("user_id")String user_id, @Param("datetime") Timestamp datetime, @Param("function_code") int function_code, @Param("ip_address") String ipAddress);
    }
```

Execution of this method on http request does works out.

I'd want to write junit tests on H2 database which verifies record is inserted correctly. for which I am using test profile. inserting record on test method with H2 dependency also seem to work - however I currently don't see a way to verify existence of record.

Any suggestions How to achieve it?

Ps. I understand this is possible with either `@JpaRepository`(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository) or `@CrudRepository` but I'd prefer not to use them as using Repository and distinct method will make application light weight.

Comment: At any moment you can use spring `JdbcTemplate`, which requires just datasource (you can Autowired it in your test) and write simple select for checking everything what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can `@Mock` your `@Repository` object and with `org.mockito.Mockito.verify` and will be able to verify if the Sql written above does gets executed upon calling. (authentication request)
ie. mock `AuditRepository` and verify object.

```
verify(auditRepository).recordUserAudit(user_id,datetime, function_code, ipAddress);
```